# Discarding rows using mySQL views

Tags: mysql, view

I created a view and could successfully execute the query:

Here is the output.

```
customer_ID Item_number Frequency
1            53           10
1             64           10
2             82           11
2              64          11
2              11           9
```

I need to return only the highest frequency rows ie.

```
customer_ID   Item_number Frequency
1              53          10
1              64          10
2              82          11
2              64          11
```

Help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't start with the view.

Comment: wirte condition where frequency >= 10

Answer (score 0):

You can select the highest frequency for each customer and make an inline table and join with the main table, that will solve your problem.

For example:

```
select a.* from your_tab_1 a
join (select customer_id,max(frequency) as frequency from your_tab_1 group by customer_id) b
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.frequency = b.frequency;
```

Comment: This does not work. However thanks for your help.